Add_to_cart, purchase, begin_checkout events without products
I'm trying to setup a measurement plan in a website with GA4. I have a form to ask for information and I would to use ecommerce events: add_to_cart, begin_checkout, purchase, etc.
I'm worried because users can't choose a product in this form, that is, there aren't product features to send to GTM. This make sense? Is it possible to use ecommerce events without product information
Thanks
